# Show number of events in primefaces schedule

Tags: events, primefaces, scheduler

I am using primefaces(3.4.2) scheduler component.

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/schedule.jsf

I have to show number of events on particular date

```
  <p:schedule style="width:600px;margin-left:200px;" initialDate="#{scheduleController.initDate}" value="#{scheduleController.eventModel}" id="myschedule" widgetVar="myschedule" view="month" leftHeaderTemplate="prev" rightHeaderTemplate="next" centerHeaderTemplate="title">                           

</p:schedule>
```

Is there any way to show this ?
Plz help